# How to get dinamically-loaded content from this website using scrapy-splash?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to get data from this [website](https://www.metrocuadrado.com/bodega/arriendo) using scrapy-splash but im not able to extract data. I want to get data about each real state like href, price, etc. Here is my code:

in *setings.py*:

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"

SPLASH_ENABLED = True


DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050/'

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

my spider:

```
class M2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = "m2"
    allowed_domains = ['metrocuadrado.com']
    start_urls = [
            'https://www.metrocuadrado.com/bodega/arriendo'
            ]
    
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,callback= self.parse, 
                               endpoint='render.html',
                               args={'wait': 10},)
                  
    def parse(self, response):
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
        real_states= response.selector.xpath(".//a[@class='sc-bdVaJa ebNrSm']").getall()

        print("real_states")
```

The output print is an empty list []. I am new to splash. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do instead is this:

Send a request to https://www.metrocuadrado.com/results/_next/static/chunks/commons.8afec6af6d5add2097bf.js, in the response you'll find an API-key if you search for "X-Api-Key". So that can be extracted easily with regex, something like: `re.findall(r'"X-Api-Key":"(\w+)"')`.

Then, when you've extracted the API key, send a request to https://www.metrocuadrado.com/rest-search/search?seo=/bodega/arriendo&from=0&size=50, which is the hidden API in the website you sent. To get a valid response you have to attach the header like this

```
scrapy.Request(
    url=url_variable,
    headers={
        "x-api-key": api_key_variable_from_prev_step
    }
)
```

From that API you get JSON formatted data which is usually more reliable than parsing the html since that changes more oftan.

Comment: Your answer was very useful but I am having some problems to obtain all items. 
When I sent the request to  https://www.metrocuadrado.com/rest-search/search?seo=/bodega/arriendo&from=0&size=50 I obtained the first 50 elements but when I sent the next request to https://www.metrocuadrado.com/rest-search/search?seo=/bodega/arriendo&from=50&size=50 I keep getting the same 50 items previously obtained, what I can be doing wrong?

Comment: Try with this url, found it when pagination the site in chrome inspect.
https://www.metrocuadrado.com/rest-search/search?realEstateTypeList=bodega&realEstateBusinessList=arriendo&from=50&size=50

Comment: this works for me, but I have another little "problem", I am able to obtain only 10000 items, could you help me once again please?

Comment: I think the site is limited to provide only 10.000 items. If yo u look at the normal site you'll see that you can paginate to max page 200. So I don't think there's a way to work around that unfortunately.